# c# epplus not filling background color of cell

Tags: c#, epplus

Ok I am stumped the set font works and sets the correct cell. The Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor does not work. It literally does nothing. Am I missing something? Every search I do that syntax should work.
Yes this is reading a data table dt that is not the issue the loop works properly.

```
int startupRow = 2; // row 1 is header

for (int row = startupRow; row <= dt.Rows.Count; row++)
{
    //if allocation check is populated it will have a value > 0
    if (Convert.ToInt32(workSheet.Cells[row, 8].Value) > 0)
    {
        //if Balance Remaining Barrels <  allocation check
        if (Convert.ToInt32(workSheet.Cells[row, 7].Value) < Convert.ToInt32(workSheet.Cells[row, 8].Value))
        {
            //set the font to red 
            var cell = workSheet.Cells[row, 7];
            cell.Style.Font.Color.SetColor(System.Drawing.Color.Red);
            cell.Style.Font.Bold = true;

            //Setting the background color to red
            cell.Style.Fill.PatternType = OfficeOpenXml.Style.ExcelFillStyle.Solid;
            cell.Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(System.Drawing.Color.Red);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Also tried this and it sill doesn't set the background color. I upgraded to the newest version of epplus. Also tired and old version thinking it maybe an issue with nuget package.using (ExcelRange Rng = workSheet.Cells[row, 7])                                                         
                                                        Rng.Style.Fill.PatternType = ExcelFillStyle.Solid;
                                                        Rng.Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(Color.Red);
                                                    }

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my own question so hopefully this helps someone else.
The border has to be last in the formatting. Certain elements take precedent over other elements and they will disappear.